# ThreeJS Animate Object3D.lookAt oddity

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to animate the lookAt method of an Object3D to lookAt a target Vector3. My Tween function traces floating points as per the incrementing scalarMultiplyVal (0.0 - 1.0), but no matter what I try the Object3D is already looking at the target before the tween starts. Very odd.

```
TweenMax.to( this, 5, {scalarMultiplyVal:1, onUpdate:function(){
            let targetVector = new THREE.Vector3( target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z ).multiplyScalar( scalarMultiplyVal );
            console.log( targetVector ) // logs "animating" x,y,z values as expected
            displayObject.lookAt( targetVector ); // does not animate. Already fulling looking at target.position ( scalarMultiplyVal = 1.0 )
        }});
```

Essentially I'm trying to have my Object3D animate/turn to look at a new vector3 periodically, but instead the Object3D is already fully looking at the target.position, and disregarding the vector multiplication. Very odd.  Any advice will be a great help!

Comment: Multiplying the vector will only make it longer, not change the angle it's pointing at. You need to lerp between the existing target vector and the final one, or you need to animate the target position itself and not try to juggle the target vector over multiple frames.

Comment: @AndyRay that's good advice, I should have known that already! Many thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing an animation with `Object3D.lookAt()` I highly recommend to use [Quaternion.rotateTowards()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion.rotateTowards). The method is based on Unity's [Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html). It internally performs a slerp which is ideal for your use case. The following example demonstrate the usage of `Quaternion.rotateTowards()`.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_math_orientation_transform

`three.js R104`